# Directly Execute Objective C's AppDelegate in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridge-header

I have a complete Objective C Project for IOS App. However, I would like to open a new project in Swift.

I have successfully mixed and matched Swift and Objective C in the same project like using header-bridge file . And I can call methods from the old source(Objective C) in Swift AppDelegate.

The situation right now is the Objective C project consists of a lot of files for example there are many AppDelegate with different parameters like AppDelegate.m, AppDelegate+abc.m, AppDelegate+dfg.m, AppDelegate+ppp.m....

I would like to ask whether I can directly run the Object C's AppDelegate in AppDelegate.swift and make the whole app run? Or Any other solutions?

Comment: Use header-bridge file.

Comment: Yes, I used. And import ed the AppDelegate.h in Objective C. But nothing happens. @the_dahiya_boy

Comment: It is the only method you have to use. If you facing any issue with header-bridge then write in your question.

Comment: Yes that is what I would like to ask how to execute the AppDelegate.m from OC in AppDelegate.swift? Thanks@the_dahiya_boy

Comment: What OC means? Actually IDK its abbrevation.

Answer (score 0):

For header-bridge get

- [stack-answer-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) and
- Read [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

First try this. Most of your query just solved here. Don't this is simple and perfect.

If you still have doubt then let me know.